# Unable to run Rhapsody application via Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, rhapsody

when we run a Rhapsody application via Jenkins.
My scenario:

1) I need to get details about various diagrams in a Rhapsody model.
2) I have written Java code using api provided by Rhapsody to get the details of various diagrams.
3) this java code is made into Jar and is run via command line, works fine by invoking Rhapsody in background.
4) when this same command is put in jenkins to run as windows command, the job fails, 
The code is able to connect to Rhapsody Instance, but somehow unable to open a project.

Did anyone resolve this type of issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes I faced this issue when running a plugin in jenkins where I was not able to open the rhapsody instance as it was throwing an examption.
To solve make user which runs the jenkins job has the license for rhapsody if yes try to open your rhapsody project manually and run the script from the job.
Hope these solution works for you